# Error with decision tree prediction

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees, prediction

I write this script in R about decision tree.

```
library(class)
library(ggplot2)
library(gmodels)
library(scales)
library(caret)
library(tidyverse)


db_data <- iris
row_train <- sample(nrow(iris), nrow(iris)*0.8)
db_train <- iris[row_train,]
db_test <- iris[-row_train,]

unique(db_train$Species)
table(db_train$Species)
model_dt<-train(Species ~ ., data = db_train, method = "rpart",tuneLenght = 9)
summary(model_dt)
#-------

#PREDICTION NEW RECORD
#-------
test_data <- db_test
db_test$predict <- predict(model_dt, newdata=test_data, interval='confidence')
confusionMatrix(data=factor(db_test$predict),reference=factor(db_test$Species))
```

but when I run `model_dt` I have this error:

```
  Error in train(Species ~ ., data = db_train, method = "rpart", tuneLenght = 9) : 
  unused arguments (data = db_train, method = "rpart", tuneLenght = 9)
```

why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that is wrong is the spelling of `tuneLength`. The code has `tuneLenght = 9`. Maybe that will get the program further.